# SQlite bitwise operation in update

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I've an sqlite3 db in which a table is defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE test (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NUM INTEGER);
```

with the following data in it

```
ID   NUM       
---  ---
1    15
```

I want to perform bitwise operators on all the values of the `NUM` column and update in place.

This is what I tried just to perform bitwise operation on that field.

```
sqlite> select NUM from test | 20;
```

> Error: near "|": syntax error

How do I perform a bitwise operation and also how to save the result in the same place?

It would be very helpful if this is done in the same command. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
UPDATE test
SET NUM = NUM | 20
WHERE ...  ;
```

Output:

```
Before
1 - 15
After
1 - 31
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=d8a101cf7d360ba3c00db79dc6f4f324)**

---

## EDIT:

> Just for displaying result without updating, I've used this command. select NUM = NUM | 20 from test;. But it is giving some other result: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=04a9fe5251b377f96551e65ecded053e

```
select NUM = NUM | 20 from test;
-- is the same as:
SELECT NUM = (NUM | 20) FROM test;
```

What you really want is:

```
select NUM | 20 AS NUM from test;
```

Comment: Thanks.. Worked. I could update all the column at once now. `update test set NUM = NUM | 20;`

Comment: Just for displaying result without updating, I've used this command. `select NUM = NUM | 20 from test;`. But it is giving some other result. Link: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=04a9fe5251b377f96551e65ecded053e